# How does flying at ECON computed speeds optimise fuel burn.?

Tags: airbus-a320, fctm

I read in the FCTM GREEN OPERATING PROCUDURES that it’s recommended to fly at ECON computed speeds throughout the flight profile to optimise speed in accordance with the CI.

Comment: I am unsure what your actual question is. Are you trying to understand what is ECON speed, or how is it calculated, or how does it relate to the Cost Index, etc.?

Answer (score 3):

The key is the word 'Econ', which has nothing to do with 'Fuel Burn'. The 'Econ' setting is a MIN COST method of operating, taking into account not just the cost of the fuel, but also the other operating costs of the airplane.
If your hourly costs (maintenance, crew) are high, then you'd burn fuel to get there fast with reduced hours. If your hourly costs are low, then it's worth flying slow, and thus conserving fuel.